# Send New User Email Confirmation to specific email address domains

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In my Magento install, I have disabled the "Require Emails Confirmation" feature as I do not need it for all users. I would however like to have users of a specific domain, "foo.com" to actually receive this email confirmations.

Once they confirm their email address with the emailed link, I would then like to add them to a specific group.

Can anyone provide me any direction as to where I should start with this type of Magento modification? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend or Override

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

public function createPostAction()
{
    if (true === $validationResult) {
        $customer->save();

        // Do your custom Code here to match the domains you want to make Confirmation Required for them.
        $patterns = array('@foo.com','@boo.com','@bar.com');
        $patterns_flattened = implode('|', $patterns);
        if ( preg_match('/'. $patterns_flattened .'/i', $customer->getEmail(), $matches) )
        {  
            $customer->setIsConfirmationRequired(true);
        }

       if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
            $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmation', $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl());
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your e-mail for confirmation link. To resend confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.',
                Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())
           ));
            $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
            return;
        }
        else {
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);
            $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

So you can do it in both ways

Enable Activation email and set `$customer->setIsConfirmationRequired(false);` if the email didn't match the domain you want to validate ( Recommended )

Disable Activation email and set `$customer->setIsConfirmationRequired(true);` if the email match the domain you want to validate

Thanks

Comment: FYI. In version 1.7.2, you need to notice following points:

1. change:
$customer->setIsConfirmationRequired(true);
to
$customer->setConfirmation(null);

2. after that, you need to save it:
$customer->save();